# How to improve mongodb group query performance

Tags: mongodb, solr, aggregation-framework

I am currently using solr to store public tweet information. I have field such as content, sentiment, keywords, tstamp, language, tweet_id to capture the essence of the tweet. I am also evaluating Mongodb for the same use case. I am trying to benchmark mongodb and solr each having **one million records**.

What I have observed is that group query in mongodb are 2.5 to 3 times slower than the facet query of solr.

The following mongodb query

```
db.tweets.aggregate(
 [
   {
     $group : {
       _id : "$sentiment", 
       total : { $sum : 1 }
     }
   }
 ]
)
```

takes 481ms. I have index applied on sentiment field.

However the same thing in solr using facet query takes 93ms.

Is there any other configuration in mongodb which needs to be set so as to improve the group query performance in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

A [`$group` operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and a facet search are not really comparable operations and the `$group` won't use an index.  It looks like you are trying to compute the number of documents with each distinct value of `sentiment`. MongoDB doesn't have a specific function for this. For a specific value, a much better operation to get the count would be

```
db.collection.count({ "sentiment" : sentiment })
```

and you can get all of the distinct values with

```
db.collection.distinct("sentiment")
```

Both of these can use an index `{ "sentiment" : 1 }`. You will need multiple queries to get counts for multiple values of `sentiment` so it's not as convenient as Solr. Faceted searching is a core competency of full text search engines, so it's not surprising this is easier in Solr than MongoDB. MongoDB and Solr meant for totally different uses, so I can't say I'd see why you'd benchmark one versus the other. It's like racing a boat against a car.

Comment: If a field contains say for e.g. 80 distinct values then in that case the above approach is not feasible. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right. Then you could use an aggregation like the one above to find it, but then there wouldn't be an index used.